# Best resources for learning Ruby/Cucumber/Rspec test suite organization and refactoring

Tags: page-objects, ruby, watir-webdriver, cucumber

I'm working with a Cucumber suite that needs refactoring and organization. The end goal is to have a maintainable suite of tests that matter enough that developers will stop if the cucumber tests are red on CI. The features and steps need to be organized and clear.

I'm looking specifically for

```
-Cucumber centric books relating to test planning.
-Books about using OOP principles in ruby
-Katas and hands on exercises set up for Cucumber... similar to the Gilded Rose Kata.
```

I use watir-webdriver, page-object, factory girl, and lots of other OAuth gems, but I'm also needing to make some support code. An agile coach on the team has recommended test driving the support code with RSpec, so I'm also interested in that.

Any suggestions are welcome!

Comment: David, your question is too broad as stated.  How about splitting it up into multiple, specific questions?

Answer (score 0):

The book Cucumber and Cheese seems to fit the bill

https://leanpub.com/cucumber_and_cheese